# SSRS Reporting Services - Bold numbers alternately with non bold

Tags: reporting-services, expression, bold

I would like to give me some help with an expression.
Im using SSRS Reporting Services and i would like to make an expression for a value with 25 characters from SQL, in which alternatively every 4 characters, the characters will be bold like

RF16**9000**1800**0000**1234**5678**9

Do you have any idea how i can do this without using HTML tags?

I am not an ssrs expert and so i find it very difficult to create such an expression with my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a series of placeholders.

In this example, I have a table showing the original data and then to the right there is a column that will contain 7 placeholders. (I only show the first one/two here)

[image]

To add a placeholder, click inside the textbox so you get a cursor in there, then right-click and choose "Create Placeholder". Create 7 of these and then set the value expression in turn to the following

```
=Mid(Fields!myText.Value, 1, 4)
=Mid(Fields!myText.Value, 5, 4)
=Mid(Fields!myText.Value, 9, 4)
=Mid(Fields!myText.Value, 13, 4)
=Mid(Fields!myText.Value, 17, 4)
=Mid(Fields!myText.Value, 21, 4)
=Mid(Fields!myText.Value, 25, 1)
```

**Note:** The final expression selects only 1 character

Now just click each alternate placeholder and set the font to bold, that's it.

The final design looks like this...

[image]

Here's the result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Alan! Thats exctly what i wanted!